# How to fetch cells based on combo box selection in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet like this :

[image]

Also I have a userform like this :

[image]

So if a user selects say `a` from `side` and `aa` from `top`, The form should display all items corresponding to it from 1,2,3,4 in a `textbox` under this `combo box`
ie, there will be four textboxes with values `s,qr,q,eef`

How can i do this??

Answer (score 1):

Here's some pseudo-code that you can use as a starting point. I'm assuming that the *top* dropdown returns an integer from 0 to 3, and the *side* dropdown returns integers such as 1 for a, 2 for b, etc...  Then the code will use the offset function to position the cell properly so that each *textbox* gets the text from the correct cell.  For example, if side = 1 and top = 0 then the cell for Textbox1 will be the one offset from A2 by 1 row, 1 columns, and if side = 2 and top =1 then the cell for Textbox1 will be the one offset from A2 by 2 rows and and 5 columns. Let me know if you have questions.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim r As Range, side As Integer, top As Integer
Set r = Range("A2")
Textbox1 = r.Offset(side, top * 4 + 1)
TextBox2 = r.Offset(side, top * 4 + 2)
TextBox3 = r.Offset(side, top * 4 + 3)
TextBox4 = r.Offset(side, top * 4 + 4)
End Sub
```